# ROC curve for multi-class classification without one vs all in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class classification problem with 9 different classes. I am using the `AdaBoostClassifier` class from scikit-learn to train my model *without* using the one vs all technique, as the number of classes is very high and it might be inefficient.

I have tried using the tips from the documentation in scikit learn [1], but there the one vs all technique is used, which is substantially different. In my approach I only get one prediction per event, i.e. if I have n classes, the outcome of the prediction is a single value within the n classes. For the one vs all approach, on the other hand, the outcome of the prediction is an array of size n with a sort of likelihood value per class.

[1]
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py

The code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Matplotlib plotting library for basic visualisation
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn import preprocessing


# Read data
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')

# Create the dependent variable class
# This will substitute each of the n classes from 
# text to number
factor = pd.factorize(df['target_var'])
df.target_var= factor[0]
definitions = factor[1]

X = df.drop('target_var', axis=1)
y = df['target_var]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)

bdt_clf = AdaBoostClassifier(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2),
    n_estimators=250,
    learning_rate=0.3)

bdt_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = bdt_clf.predict(X_test)

#Reverse factorize (converting y_pred from 0s,1s, 2s, etc. to their original values
reversefactor = dict(zip(range(9),definitions))
y_test_rev = np.vectorize(reversefactor.get)(y_test)
y_pred_rev = np.vectorize(reversefactor.get)(y_pred)
```

I tried directly with the roc curve function, and also binarising the labels, but I always get the same error message.

```py
def multiclass_roc_auc(y_test, y_pred):
    lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
    lb.fit(y_test)
    y_test = lb.transform(y_test)
    y_pred = lb.transform(y_pred)
    return roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)

multiclass_roc_auc(y_test, y_pred_test)
```

The error message is:

> ValueError: multilabel-indicator format is not supported

How could this be sorted out? Am I missing some important concept?

Comment: I always think as ROC curves for binary classifiers. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: @doctorlove maybe the ROC curve is not the ideal approach, but then, how could I get similar information in a multi-class problem? I am trying to find out and be as sure as possible about the performance and quality of my model

Comment: So, what are you trying to do? Try to find if your classifier is "optimal", in some sense? Is accuracy good enough? Figure out what you want to know then work backwards to find a suitable measure